# Change layout without calling onCreate

Tags: android, layout, android-configchanges

I have an activity with two layout files, one each for portrait and landscape modes. I see that the onCreate method is called each time I change orientation. I tried using

```
android:configChanges = "orientation"
```

in the manifest file, but it only reads the portrait layout. Is there a way I can set the layout to the landscape mode without calling onCreate?

Comment: onCreate is automatically called when you change orientation.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `android:configChanges = "orientation"`, you must override the `onConfigurationChanged(...)` method of your `Activity`. Check the `newConfig` parameter for the new orientation then manually set the layout you want.

See the following links:

[onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29)

[Handling the Configuration Change Yourself](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange)

Comment: This would mean that I have to save and reuse my activity data anyway. Am I right?

Comment: Not as far as I understand it. Using `android:configChanges = "orientation"` prevents the `Activity` from being destroyed/re-created as the result of an orientation change and `onConfigurationChanged(...)` is called instead. Any other configuration change will, however, result in the `Activity` being destroyed/re-created and `onConfigurationChanged(...)` will not be called.

Comment: @RameezHussain : I've added another link to my answer which explains handling the configuration change.

Answer (score 0):

You could create two layout folders. One for portrait mode and one for landscape.
layout and layout-land.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fact of life with android. You need to develop your activity around the fact it can be destroyed at any minute due to a configuration change like the screen's orientation changing.
Save all the the information used to build the screen in on pause and recreate it in onCreate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your activity be only in landscape mode, you set this attribute for the activity in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

You can put your layout.xml files in such folders for different screen orientations:

- res\layout-land
- res\layout-port

Comment: This is exactly what I have done. It still seems to use the layout file which I have placed in the layout-port folder

Comment: add the attribute in the AndroidManifest.xml:
                android:screenOrientation="landscape"

Comment: The activity is for both orientations. This will limit it to just the landscape mode. This is not what I'm looking for. :)